# A shorter word to describe a secondhand marketplace?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking if there is a word that describe a place where people can selling/buying used things.

For example: Seller come to sell their old things which they never use it anymore for whoever need it, for a cheaper price. And buyer come to buy stuffs for lower price instead of buying expensive new one.

I have found word "thrift shop" so far. However, it doesn't look like exactly same meaning as above. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Thanks all!

Comment: [Flea market](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flea-market).

Comment: Depending on the goods, the names vary. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-hand_shop

Comment: @Rathony Didn't mean to hog your answer. Network is jerky in India. :)

Comment: @Rathony There is no such thing as enough reps. :)

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests

Comment: To properly answer the question more details about the type of place you have in mind needs to be supplied.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See **flea market**

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flea%20market)

> a usually outdoor market in which old, used and second hand goods are sold.

Answer (score 6):

Swap meet is also possible here.

[OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/swap-meet?q=swap+meet)

> swap meet : NOUN
>
> chiefly North American
>
> 1  A gathering at which enthusiasts or collectors
> trade or exchange items of common interest: a computer swap meet More
> example sentences At the swap meet you're either exchanging parts or
> cash. Proceeds from table rentals at the swap meet will be put towards
> the refurbishment of computers for needy Edmonton households. Or maybe
> you found one of your father's chips in an old trunk or stumbled on
> one at a swap meet and wondered what it might be worth as a
> collector's item. Get more examples
>
> 2 A flea market.
>
> Example sentences:
>
> I found the photo of the Lightning at a local swap meet and you can
> see why it attracted my interest.
>
> Almost every city has regular swap
> meets or collectible shows and careful browsing can usually find a
> variety of WWII items, including post cards.
>
> A connoisseur of thrift
> stores and swap meets, she understands the collector mentality, the
> longing to affiliate and define oneself through things.

Answer (score 2):

[Car boot sale](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/car-boot-sale)

> An outdoor sale at which people sell unwanted possessions, typically
>   from the boots of their cars.

This is specifically a British term. Can also be written as "carboot sale" or just "boot sale".

Comment: Car boot sale is also used in Australia.

Comment: I suppose, if the direct equivalent were to be used in the US, it would be "car trunk sale" or "trunk sale"; I'm not a USian, so don't take my word for it, but I have never heard of such a term.

Comment: In the US, [garage or yard sales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garage_sale) are probably more common.

Comment: There's a slight difference - in a garage sale (term we also use in Australia) or yard sale, buyers come to someone's (generally the seller's) home; in a car boot sale, multiple sellers all drive their stuff to an agreed place.

Answer (score 1):

[Consignment store](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consignment%20store):

> a store to which people bring items that they no longer want (such as old clothes, shoes, and equipment) to have them sold.
>
> **E.g.** I brought some old clothes to a consignment store, and when they were sold I received a portion of the sale price. (M-W)

More info and origin in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consignment_store).

Comment: I have never heard this in the UK. While it seems to be a US usage, the Wikipedia article suggests that this is an east Asian idea and that it seems to have moved away from used  or second-hand goods

Comment: A consignment store is a place you take your stuff, and when it sells, you get a percentage. It tends to be for better quality stuff than what a flea market would normally handle. There are a dozen or so in my small hometown. Mostly, they deal in furniture, jewelry, antiques, medical devices, and women's clothing. The ones for medical devices are often charity operations run by churches or civic groups.  http://selectfurnitureconsignment.com/hendersonville-consignment-shops/

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, "second hand shop" is common usage. There is also a large overlap with charity shops - most charity shops sell second hand goods, and more second hand shops are run and branded by charities as part of their fund-raising efforts.

I've not come across the term thrift shop, except in American drama.

Comment: second hand shop is ubiquitously used in many places around the world. In Chinese it is 二手 (two-hand).

Answer (score -1):

I like to use **bazaar**

> A market (as in the Middle East) consisting of rows of shops or stalls selling miscellaneous goods

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bazaar

---

Side-note:

Although **flea market** is correct, there is the possibility of being identified with the [presence of fleas and uncleanliness](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/272402/63734).

Comment: I think your side note is unfounded.

Comment: @Jim That's why it's a side note. I am not stating a fact but rather pointing out a possibility of misconception.